# phpmyadmin showing mysql error when creating table?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Im trying to create a table using the following query.phpmyadmin does not allow it.What im i doing wrong

```
CREATE TABLE main (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY(id),
dealername VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
product VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
date VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
sublocation VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
phone1 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
phone2 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
auth VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
lat VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
lon VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

ERROR:
*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id), dealername VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, product VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, type VAR' at line 2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `(id)`

```
CREATE TABLE main (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
dealername VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
product VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
date VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`desc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
sublocation VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
phone1 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
phone2 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
auth VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
lat VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
lon VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

The syntax of the table create statement is wrong. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).
The name of the column after `Primary key` is not expected.

And `desc` is a reserved word in `sql` so you have to escape it or better take an other column name.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove `(id)`
2. **desc** is mysql keyword.

put it in *backticks* like this, if you still want to use desc as your column name.

```
 CREATE TABLE main (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    dealername VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    product VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    date VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `desc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    sublocation VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    phone1 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    phone2 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    auth VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    brands VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lat VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    lon VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
    );
```

Comment: I have upvoted both answers but the other answer already had the 'desc' ,just did not notice.So i accepted it.Thanks